# Quoted string used in command

Tags: bash, cygwin

I thought I was quoting correctly, but I can't work out why I am getting these different results. Test directory:

```
ls /d/Temp/test
```

shows:

```
textFile.txt  textFile.txt.bak
```

And my test script is:

```
cd /d/Temp/test
excludeString="-not -iwholename '*.svn*' -not -iwholename '*.bak*'"
find -P . $excludeString -type f -name "*.*"
echo =======================
find -P . -not -iwholename '*.svn*' -not -iwholename '*.bak*' -type f -name "*.*"
```

and the results:

```
./textFile.txt
./textFile.txt.bak
=======================
./textFile.txt
```

Is this a quoting issue or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash doesn't interpret string data as code, since this is extremely unpredictable and leads to security vulnerabilities.

[Shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) correctly suggests using an array instead:

```
excludeParams=(-not -iwholename '*.svn*' -not -iwholename '*.bak*')
find -P . "${excludeParams[@]}" -type f -name "*.*"
```

Comment: Wow, I thought I was going crazy.. thank you very much - and I never knew about Spellcheck either, which raises the question: why wasn't I told! :)